# MYSQL: SELECT * FROM `user_log` WHERE `id` is sequential and `username` == EQUAL in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched high and long for an answer to this.
I have a database that collects data whenever a user logs onto our network.
Some users are complaining of disconnections, so I would like to crawl the database, and find any sections where a user is appearing in the database on 3 sequential rows.

Database Structure is:

```
ID          USER

1           MIKE
2           JOHN
3           MIKE
4           MIKE
5           MIKE
6           JOHN
7           JOHN
8           MIKE
```

I would like the query to return the below (Mike user logged on with 3 sequential ID's)

```
ID          USER

3           MIKE
4           MIKE
5           MIKE
```

I'm stumped as to how to even attack this.

I'm thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_log` WHERE `id` IS sequential??? and `username` == ???
```

Possibly a sub-select ?

Comment: Edit the question title and put your current tile inside the post...

Comment: Whats my current tile ? This is my first post. I'm sorry if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is establish a grouping identifier for each consecutive sequence of users, and then use that as a temporary table to perform a query that groups on that new grouping identifier. From that, we just grab any group that has three or more rows, and can use the `min/max` values of the `id` to show your range.  We need to use variables to accomplish this.

```
 select min(id), max(id), user
  from (
    select if(@prev != user, if(@prev := user, @rc := @rc +1, @rc := @rc + 1), @rc) g,
           id, user
      from log, (select @prev := -1, @rc := 0) q
      order by id desc
  ) q
  group by g
  having count(g) >= 3;
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21feb/3)

this part: `(select @prev := -1, @rc := 0) q` initialises the variables for us so that we can do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative doesn't use variables. It creates two temporary tables, a and b, containing names and either the next id number (in table a) or the one after that (in table b), and then checks for each entry in the original table whether there is a corresponding entry in the two temporary tables with matching name.

```
SELECT
user_log.username, user_log.id-2 FROM user_log,
(SELECT username, id, (id+1) as nxt FROM user_log) as a,
(SELECT username, id, (id+2) as nxtnxt FROM user_log) as b
WHERE
user_log.id=a.nxt and
user_log.username=a.username and
user_log.id=b.nxtnxt and
user_log.username=b.username;
```

It returns name and the location (id) of the "event". It doesn't return the sequence as you requested, since that seems redundant to me.  `id-2` is used in the result because the structure natively returns the last id in the triplet, but the last or middle id might be just as useful depending on how you're going to use the result.

One of the things to watch out for is if you have four entries in a row with the same name, it will give you two results.

Anyone searching for longer sequences is better off using [pala_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4692019/pala)'s variable method, but this method is also useful if you want to find other patterns. For example, if you wanted to find sequences like 'Mike', something, 'Mike', something, 'Mike', you could simply replace id+1 with id+2 and id+2 with id+4 in the subqueries.

Comment: this will break on anything that doesn't have contiguous id's -- ie, any environment that uses multi-master replication, or if a row gets deleted. etc.